# Properly handling a malloc call in Lua binding C code

Tags: c, lua, malloc

I'm writing a small [Lua](http://www.lua.org) binding library. Currently I provide a very simple struct to hold Key/Values, where my `value` is a `void pointer`.

```
struct kvPair {
       enum EVENT_TYPE type;
       char *key;
       void *value;
   };

typedef struct kvPair KeyValuePair;

KeyValuePair kvPairWithNumber(char *key, float number)
{
    KeyValuePair kv;
    float *aux = malloc(sizeof(float)); // <-- help
    *aux = number;
    kv.key = key;
    kv.type = NUMBER;
    kv.value = aux;
    return kv;
}
```

I was wondering for this kind of use case... what could be a good way to handle the malloc ? I don't really want to do:

```
if (aux == NULL) {
    exit(0);
}
```

Perhaps I could pre-allocate a block of memory and maybe override the malloc call with my own simpler implementation (custom memory allocator with a simple stack?)

Would like to receive feedback and examples, simplicity is preferred.

Comment: Why not store the value in the struct (perhaps in a union) instead of storing a pointer?

Comment: that could be even better... could you write a code example? :)

Comment: I ended up using a C union.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to exit. No script or extension should crash the whole interpreter.

There are basically two methods to express an error. The first method is to use [lua_error](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_error) or [luaL_error](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#luaL_error), which are provided by the C API. The second method is more of a policy: [return `nil` and an error message](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.3.html) (which is commonly combined with `assert`).

You're writing your extension in C, so you are basically stuck with C style error handling via return codes. You will most likely need to change your function signatures to support this.

```
int kvPairWithNumber(KeyValuePair * kv, char *key, float number)
{
    float *aux = malloc(sizeof(float));
    if (aux == NULL) {
        return 0;
        // note: you could instead just put lua_error here
    }
    *aux = number;
    kv->key = key;
    kv->type = NUMBER;
    kv->value = aux;
    return 1;
}
```

You could then handle the error in the Lua function:

```
int my_lua_function(lua_State * L)
{
    KeyValuePair kv = {0};

    // first method:
    if (!kvPairWithNumber(&kv, "asdf", 1.0)) {
        luaL_error(L, "could not create pair!");
    }

    // second method:
    if (!kvPairWithNumber(&kv, "asdf", 1.0)) {
        lua_pushnil(L);
        lua_pushstring(L, "could not create a pair!");
        return 2;
    }
}
```

The Lua code using your extension would look something like this:

```
-- first method:
local result = xpcall(my_lua_function, error_handler)

-- note: if you need to pass args, you will need a closure
local result = xpcall(function() my_lua_function(x, y, z) end, error_handler)

-- second method:
local result = assert(my_lua_function())
```